# Unable to push my commits due to master.lock

Tags: git

I'm unable to push my commits to my git repository.
Although the git push command seems to finish correctly, it always leads to the creation of a lock file which is not deleted, and then I can't see my commits on the repository.

To be more precise, here is an example with two workspaces (clone1 and clone2) :

`[clone1] git commit -a`
==> commit is created in clone1 local repository

`[clone1] git push`
==> No error. However an origin/refs/heads/master.lock file is created and not deleted.

`[clone2] git pull`
==> git says "Already up-to-date". But commit from clone1 is not retreived !

`[clone1] git push`
==> git error : "fatal: Unable to create '/MyGitRepository/TestHelper_git_bug/refs/heads/master.lock': File exists.
If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

`[clone1] rm -f /MyGitRepository/TestHelper_git_bug/refs/heads/master.lock`
==> lock file is deleted.

`[clone1] git push`
==> Again, origin/refs/heads/master.lock is created but not automatically deleted

`[clone2] git pull`
==> Already up-to-date. Commit from clone1 is still not retreived !

If I try to push a commit from clone2, I have the same results.

I looked for a "wild" git process with `ps -ef | grep git` command, but there is none.

I tried to recreate clone1 : it looked like a good workaround at first but after a while, it went wrong again.
I also tried to recreate the git respository. Same result : ok at first but not for long.

Configuration : git 1.7.1 on Linux

Any idea ? I would really appreciate your help !

Comment: This indicates you have a bug in your version of Git (it should not leave stale lock files around). Git 1.7.1 was released in April 2010 and is now *ten years* out of date; you might consider upgrading to, say, Git 2.0, first released only *six* years ago, or perhaps to an even more modern one.

Comment: You make a point torek. I'm new to git and I use the version available at work, without wondering if it was recent or not. I will see if we can upgrade to Git 2.0 at least. Thank you !

Comment: If you're truly stuck with this version of Git, you'll just have to keep removing the lock files whenever it breaks like this. I've used 1.7.1 (back in the day) and don't remember hitting this bug that often, if ever, but it's definitely worth upgrading to 2.15 or later if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is possible when multiple Git clients are trying operation on the same repository.  Seems like in your .git repository, two processes are trying to access master.lock file.  The cloned repo may have upstream pointing incorrectly.

One way is to quit all running git clients.  Another is to delete the master.lock file from your clone-2 repo.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm not sure to understand, but isn't it a basic use of git to allow multiple git operation on the same repository ? Or did you mean local repository ? We have only 3 clients, 2 on linux platform (using command line) and one on windows (using tortoise git). Concerning the master.lock file, it's on the remote repository, not on a local one.

Answer (score 0):

If it is windows try running as administrator and commit the code.